# Google Distroless image chmod not found?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, distroless

I am using this:

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11
```

When I build my docker file,

```
 > [stage-1 6/6] RUN /chmod +x /scripts/main:
#17 0.204 /bin/sh: 1: /chmod: not found
```

Why is chmod and ls not found?

When I try to ls inside the container:

```
# /bin/sh ls
/bin/sh: 0: cannot open ls: No such file
```

Answer (score 0):

That is intentional. Conceptionally, there is nothing inside the image.  It's not as bare-bones as `scratch` but close.

If you need to perform some work, do it up front in another stage.

```
FROM python 
RUN chmod +x /tmp/foo

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11
COPY --from=0 /tmp/foo /opt/app
```

That said, in your case you may be able to get away with

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11
COPY --chmod=755 /my/local/script.py /opt/app.py
```

Comment: RUN chmod +x /tmp/foo does not work. In the final version whenI run the container, it says /bin/sh: 2: ./foo: not found. after I cd into /tmp and attempt to execute

Comment: @bonijad383, I hope you dont mean that in the litteral sense. There is no /tmp/foo. It is there to illustrate how you could use multi staging to prepare things you want to add to the distroless image.

Comment: Yes, not in literal sense. I provided the error using your example convention

Comment: @bonijad383, in that case you need to provide more info. The problem has maybe nothing to do with it being executable. It would be best if you accepted my answer or deleted this question and asked a new one with a reproducible example. Technically, your answer why chmod was not found has been answered here.