# Distroless weird issue chmod

Tags: docker, dockerfile, distroless

I am trying to copy the outputs to distroless image
The `scripts` folder contain a python file named `start`

```
FROM <some image> as custom-image


RUN mkdir scripts

COPY scripts/start scripts/start


FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3
COPY --from=custom-image /scripts /scripts
```

when I run the container and go into the terminal:

```
# cd scripts
# ./start
/bin/sh: 3: ./start: Permission denied
#
```

Now when I add the chmod line:

```
RUN chmod +x scripts/start

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3
COPY --from=custom-image /scripts /scripts
```

and I attempt to run the `start` script in terminal again:

```
/bin/sh: 3: ./start: not found
```

Comment: Does `start` have a `#!` shebang line?

Comment: yes #!/usr/bin/env python3 @JohnKugelman

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to run this script "in terminal"?

Your final image already has an ENTRYPOINT (`[/usr/bin/python3.9]`):

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Entrypoint}}' gcr.io/distroless/python3
```

So your final stage could look something like this:

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3
COPY --from=custom-image /scripts /scripts

# not needed
# RUN chmod +x scripts/start

CMD ["/scripts/start"]
```

I also added and commnented out the `chmod` here to point out that it is not needed. Since the entrypoint for the distroless image is `/usr/bin/python3.9`, what will actually the run in the end is `/usr/bin/python3.9 scripts/start`, which means the script doesn't need to be executable.

If you don't want the `CMD` then you can just add `/scripts/start` at your `docker run <final_image>` script.

Comment: The distroless image probably doesn't contain `chmod` and it does need to be called in the build stage (or, better, on the original host system and committed to source control).

Comment: (...which in fact is the subject of [Google Distroless image chmod not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73838366/google-distroless-image-chmod-not-found).)

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze I didn't know that. I'll update my proposed solution.